# size_t 0x1<<31 is much larger than size_t 0x1<<30

Tags: c, size-t

I am confused by some behavior of `size_t` that I noticed:

```
size_t zero = 0x1 << 32;
size_t big = 0x1 << 31;
size_t not_as_big = 0x1 << 30;
printf("0x1<<32: %zx\n0x1<<31: %zx\n0x1<<30: %zx\n", zero, big, not_as_big);
```

Results in:

```
0x1<<32: 0
0x1<<31: ffffffff80000000
0x1<<30: 40000000
```

Now, I understand that `size_t` is only guaranteed to be at minimum a 16 bit unsigned integer, but I don't understand why `0x1<<31` ends up the value it did - trying to allocate 18 exabytes did a number on my program.

I'm using LLVM on x86_64.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shifting a signed integer so that 1's get into the sign bit position or even further is undefined in C, so the compiler is free to do the following:

```
0x1 << 32
```

Here the compiler sees a 32-bit int (0x1) which is shifted by 32 bits. Since the compiler is free to interpret it in a way that is consistent with more a correct shift, it interprets it as `0x1_0000_0000` and tries to convert it to 32-bit int, resulting in `0x0000_0000`, and then sees that you later assign the result to a `size_t`, which is usually 64-bit: `0x0000_0000_0000_0000`

```
0x1 << 31
```

As before, the compiler is free to do whatever it seems right with it, because the 1 bit invades the sign bit position. So the result is `0x8000_0000`, which is a negative number - `INT_MIN` to be precise. Then, it sees you convert that negative number to 64 bits, so it extends it with ones, as with all negative numbers. The result is `0xffff_ffff_8000_0000`, the smallest 32-bit signed integer stored as a signed 64-bit integer.

The correct and portable between all 64-bit platforms way to do it is:

```
((size_t)1) << 32
((size_t)1) << 31
```

Comment: Another cute way of doing it is the only useful use of a commonly useless construct: `sizeof(char)<<31`.

Answer (score 5):

`0x1` is of type `int` and in an implementation with 32-bit `int`, both expressions evaluations:

```
0x1 << 32
```

and

```
0x1 << 31
```

invoke undefined behavior.

To fix the issue (but assuming you don't want to keep `zero` object evaluating to `0`), do as is suggested in [KarolS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21791134/1119701) answer

```
(size_t) 1 << 32
```

and

```
(size_t) 1 << 31
```

This assumes a `size_t` type wider than 32-bit which is the case with clang implementation on x64.

Comment: That is a reason to not do it, and a reason the result isn't out of the ordinary. It's not an explanation of how this specific value was produced, which might be useful too.

Comment: Assuming 32-bit `unsigned`, `size_t zero = 1U << 32;` and C11 §6.5.7 3 "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined." imply to me the result could be `1`.